# Reference environment variable inside node start script

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I've got a `config` section in my `package.json` which holds 2 environment variables ( `port` & `host` ). Inside my `.js` I'd be able to use `process.env.npm_package_config_port` or `config_host` to access the values.

Below is the config section in my node app package.json. As you can see I've added two variables into it (host and port). I'm needing to reference those values in my `scripts` object (Below).

```
"config": {
    "port":"3000",
    "host": "localhost"
  },
"scripts": {
    "start": "env NODE_ENV=DEV rnws start --hostname config.host",
    .....
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to refernce the `config.host` value inside the `start script`. But this doesn't work. I've also try `NODE_ENV.config_host` to reference the value but it doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

For Windows, please try

```
"start": "env NODE_ENV=DEV rnws start --hostname %npm_package_config_host%",
```

For Linux, please try

```
"start": "env NODE_ENV=DEV rnws start --hostname $npm_package_config_host",
```

Comment: Awesome! I actually didn't think it was possible before I saw this.